Using the HDMI In port of a PC with Linux
I have an HP Envy 23 k019 All-In-One with a port that allows it to be used as a monitor. (The port is labeled HDMI In, there is a dedicated button to enable the HDMI input, and it works perfectly using the HP My Display software for Windows 8.)
However, I don't feel like using Windows 8.1 on my monitor, so I'm trying to find a way to capture the HDMI input or emulate the My Display software that enables the button.
DDCUtil shows that the display doesn't like being interfaced with - in fact, using ddccontrol -d dev:/dev/i2c-4 actually turned off the display near the end of the scan, and required a hard reset! Here's the output of ddcutil:
[easter@archmon ~]$ ddcutil getvcp known
Unable to open directory /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/drm: No such file or directory
VCP code 0x02 (New control value             ): One or more new control values have been saved (0x02)
VCP code 0x0e (Clock                         ): current value =     0, max value = 10000
VCP code 0x10 (Brightness                    ): current value =   100, max value =   100
VCP code 0x12 (Contrast                      ): current value =    80, max value =   100
VCP code 0x14 (Select color preset           ): !!! UNABLE TO FORMAT OUTPUT. mh=0xff, ml=0xff, sh=0x00, sl=0x0b
VCP code 0x16 (Video gain: Red               ): current value =    96, max value =   100
VCP code 0x18 (Video gain: Green             ): current value =   100, max value =   100
VCP code 0x1a (Video gain: Blue              ): current value =   100, max value =   100
VCP code 0x1e (Auto setup                    ): Auto setup not active (sl=0x00)
VCP code 0x20 (Horizontal Position (Phase)   ): current value = 65528, max value =   132
VCP code 0x30 (Vertical Position (Phase)     ): current value = 65534, max value =    18
VCP code 0x3e (Clock phase                   ): current value =     0, max value =    63
VCP code 0x42 (Horizontal Keystone           ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x43 (Vertical Keystone             ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x44 (Rotation                      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x46 (Top Corner Flare              ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x48 (Top Corner Hook               ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x4a (Bottom Corner Flare           ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x4c (Bottom Corner Hook            ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x52 (Active control                ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x54 (Performance Preservation      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x56 (Horizontal Moire              ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x58 (Vertical Moire                ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x59 (6 axis saturation: Red        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x5a (6 axis saturation: Yellow     ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x5b (6 axis saturation: Green      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x5c (6 axis saturation: Cyan       ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x5d (6 axis saturation: Blue       ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x5e (6 axis saturation: Magenta    ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x60 (Input Source                  ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x62 (Audio speaker volume          ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x63 (Speaker Select                ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x64 (Audio: Microphone Volume      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x66 (Ambient light sensor          ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x6b (Backlight Level: White        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x6c (Video black level: Red        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x6d (Backlight Level: Red          ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x6e (Video black level: Green      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x6f (Backlight Level: Green        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x70 (Video black level: Blue       ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x71 (Backlight Level: Blue         ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x72 (Gamma                         ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x7a (Adjust Focal Plane            ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x7c (Adjust Zoom                   ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x7e (Trapezoid                     ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x80 (Keystone                      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x82 (Horizontal Mirror (Flip)      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x84 (Vertical Mirror (Flip)        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x86 (Display Scaling               ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x87 (Sharpness                     ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x88 (Velocity Scan Modulation      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x8a (Color Saturation              ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x8c (TV Sharpness                  ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x8d (Audio mute/Screen blank       ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x8e (TV Contrast                   ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x8f (Audio Treble                  ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x90 (Hue                           ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x91 (Audio Bass                    ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x92 (TV Black level/Luminesence    ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x93 (Audio Balance L/R             ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x94 (Audio Processor Mode          ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x95 (Window Position(TL_X)         ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x96 (Window Position(TL_Y)         ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x97 (Window Position(BR_X)         ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x98 (Window Position(BR_Y)         ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x99 (Window control on/off         ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x9a (Window background             ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x9b (6 axis hue control: Red       ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x9c (6 axis hue control: Yellow    ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x9d (6 axis hue control: Green     ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x9e (6 axis hue control: Cyan      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0x9f (6 axis hue control: Blue      ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xa0 (6 axis hue control: Magenta   ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xa5 (Change the selected window    ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xaa (Screen Orientation            ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xac (Horizontal frequency          ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xae (Vertical frequency            ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xb2 (Flat panel sub-pixel layout   ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xb6 (Display technology type       ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xb7 (Monitor status                ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xb8 (Packet count                  ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xb9 (Monitor X origin              ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xba (Monitor Y origin              ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xbb (Header error count            ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xbc (Body CRC error count          ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xbd (Client ID                     ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xbe (Link control                  ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xc0 (Display usage time            ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xc2 (Display descriptor length     ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xc4 (Enable display of 'display descriptor'): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xc6 (Application enable key        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xc8 (Display controller type       ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xc9 (Display firmware level        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xca (OSD/Button Control            ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xcc (OSD Language                  ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xcd (Status Indicators             ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xce (Auxiliary display size        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xd0 (Output select                 ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xd4 (Stereo video mode             ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xd6 (Power mode                    ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xd7 (Auxiliary power output        ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xda (Scan mode                     ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xdb (Image Mode                    ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xdc (Display Mode                  ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xde (Scratch Pad                   ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]
VCP code 0xdf (VCP Version                   ): Invalid response. status code=ENXIO(-6), Display_Handle[i2c-4: fd=3]

Unlike some other devices, there is no button device listed in dmesg, lsusb, or lspci. /dev/video0 is the internal webcam, and there is a /dev/video1 device but it shows the same output as this related post, so I do not believe it is available to Linux.
The button itself, functioning properly in Windows, will show the text 'Game Mode' before switching to the input. The text onscreen uses the exact same aliased font as my Acer monitor, and cannot be alt-tabbed, ctrl-alt-deleted, or Win-R-ed out of, and keyboard inputs will only affect the Windows system, so I think that the video is displayed directly through the monitor.
If anyone has had a similar problem or if there's something clear I'm missing, please let me know! Just trying to repurpose this old PC with a nice display!
P.S. The display is labeled as HWP4224.

Update: The NVIDIA Graphics drivers weren't installed properly! My problem still isn't fixed, but ddcutil is working properly now!
Setting 0x60 to any other value makes no difference, though. Maybe it's 'application enable key' I need to set, but I'm not sure what to set it to
[easter@archmon ~]$ ddcutil getvcp known
VCP code 0x02 (New control value             ): One or more new control values have been saved (0x02)
VCP code 0x0e (Clock                         ): current value =     0, max value = 10000
VCP code 0x10 (Brightness                    ): current value =   100, max value =   100
VCP code 0x12 (Contrast                      ): current value =    80, max value =   100
VCP code 0x14 (Select color preset           ): !!! UNABLE TO FORMAT OUTPUT. mh=0xff, ml=0xff, sh=0x00, sl=0x08
VCP code 0x16 (Video gain: Red               ): current value =   100, max value =   100
VCP code 0x18 (Video gain: Green             ): current value =   100, max value =   100
VCP code 0x1a (Video gain: Blue              ): current value =   100, max value =   100
VCP code 0x1e (Auto setup                    ): Auto setup not active (sl=0x00)
VCP code 0x20 (Horizontal Position (Phase)   ): current value = 65528, max value =   132
VCP code 0x30 (Vertical Position (Phase)     ): current value = 65534, max value =    18
VCP code 0x3e (Clock phase                   ): current value =     0, max value =    63
VCP code 0x60 (Input Source                  ): DVI-1 (sl=0x03)
VCP code 0x62 (Audio speaker volume          ): Volume level: 70 (00x46)
VCP code 0x8a (Color Saturation              ): current value =    50, max value =   100
VCP code 0x8c (TV Sharpness                  ): current value =     6, max value =     8
VCP code 0x95 (Window Position(TL_X)         ): current value =    30, max value =  2047
VCP code 0x96 (Window Position(TL_Y)         ): current value =    22, max value =  2047
VCP code 0x97 (Window Position(BR_X)         ): current value =   960, max value =  2047
VCP code 0x98 (Window Position(BR_Y)         ): current value =  1080, max value =  2047
VCP code 0x9b (6 axis hue control: Red       ): current value =    30, max value =    60
VCP code 0x9c (6 axis hue control: Yellow    ): current value =    30, max value =    60
VCP code 0x9d (6 axis hue control: Green     ): current value =    30, max value =    60
VCP code 0x9e (6 axis hue control: Cyan      ): current value =    30, max value =    60
VCP code 0x9f (6 axis hue control: Blue      ): current value =    30, max value =    60
VCP code 0xa0 (6 axis hue control: Magenta   ): current value =    30, max value =    60
VCP code 0xac (Horizontal frequency          ): 38146 hz
VCP code 0xae (Vertical frequency            ): 227.86 hz
VCP code 0xb6 (Display technology type       ): Invalid value (sl=0x00)
VCP code 0xc0 (Display usage time            ): Usage time (hours) = 14336 (0x003800) mh=0xff, ml=0xff, sh=0x38, sl=0x00
VCP code 0xc6 (Application enable key        ): 0x005b
VCP code 0xc8 (Display controller type       ): Mfg: STMicroelectronics (sl=0x0d), controller number: mh=0xff, ml=0xff, sh=0x40
VCP code 0xc9 (Display firmware level        ): 1.1
VCP code 0xca (OSD/Button Control            ): Host OSD control unsupported (sl=0x00), Power button disabled, power button events enabled (sh=0x01)
VCP code 0xd6 (Power mode                    ): Invalid value (sl=0x00)
VCP code 0xdc (Display Mode                  ): Standard/Default mode (sl=0x00)
VCP code 0xdf (VCP Version                   ): 2.2


If you still have Windows available, it also has several DDC/VCP apps (e.g. the one from Nirsoft) – would it be possible to compare its output with what you get on Linux? (especially after switching the display to 'HDMI-In' mode and then blindly running the app on the computer)

Though – I'm not sure if it will actually be anything DCC-related. Given that it's an All-in-One, it's just as likely that the system firmware will have direct control over the panel input switcher, and there might be an ACPI method that the button invokes. (I have no idea how to trace those, though it's possible to dump the ACPI tables and decompile them with iasl, searching for anything of note.)

Using the ControlMyMonitor software that grawity suggested in the comments, I checked the difference between the monitor's properties in both modes! The Input Source (0x60)property was set to 17 in monitor mode, so I changed it to 17 using ddcutil setvcp 0x60 17 and it switched modes! I don't need the physical button anyway, so this is a perfect solution! Now I just need to setup a silent boot and make the command run on startup, but that's a whole different subject.
